# How to use GM_addStyle in Tampermonkey on #shadow-root (open)?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

There are extensions that make small on-page popups that in Inspection in Chrome show as `#shadow-root(open)`.

I want to customise its styles with Tampermonkey, but using `GM_addStyle(".class_name{zoom: 166%;}");` doesn't work. On native elements it works.

Comment: Create a `style` element with document.createElement and append it to that element's shadowRoot.

Comment: You can see the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668111/how-do-i-pop-up-a-custom-form-dialog-in-a-greasemonkey-script

Answer (score 0):

[`GM_addStyle()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_addStyle) appends the `<style>` element it creates to the `<head>`, therefore it can't modify the styling of Shadow DOM elements. You need to use [`GM_addElement()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_addElement).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Shadow DOM styling
// @version      0.1
// @author       double-beep
// @match        http*://example.com
// @grant        GM_addElement
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const shadowRoot = document.querySelector('element');
    const styles = `div { color: red; }`;

    GM_addElement(shadowRoot, 'style', { textContent: styles });
})();
```

If the styles aren't applied, you can create a `<script>` element instead in a similar way:

```js
GM_addElement(shadowRoot, 'script', {
    textContent: 'shadowRootElement.shadowRoot.querySelector("...").style.color = "red";'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to insert the style tag into the shadow root.

(pinching some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683439/gm-addstyle-equivalent-in-tampermonkey))

```
function addStyleToShadowRoot(shadowRoot,css) {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
addStyleToShadowRoot(customElement.shadowRoot, myCss);
```